# Wait aysnc call in for each

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs2, es6-promise

I have a function where I want to finish the first `this.findLocation()` on every loop before returning the jsonObject. The problem is when the function returns the jsonObject, some of the `findlocation` still not finished loop.

This is the code for the function:

```
generate (item) {
  let jsonObj = {}
  jsonObj.lookup = this.id
  this.fields.forEach(field => {
      if (field.prop === 'API') {
        this.findLocation(item, field).then(function (value) {
          let location = value
          if (location) jsonObj[field.prop] = location.id
        })
      } else {
        jsonObj[field.prop] = item[field.header]
      }
  })
  return jsonObj
}
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: From the duplicate post, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002/283366) shows how to use `Promise.all` to work with a collection of asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` to wait for every asynchronous operation to complete:

```
generate (item) {
  const obj = { lookup: this.id };
  const proms = this.fields.map((field) => {
    if (field.prop === 'API') {
      // Make sure to *return* the `Promise`:
      return this.findLocation(item, field).then((value) => {
        if (value) obj[field.prop] = value.id
      })
    } else {
      obj[field.prop] = item[field.header]
    }
  });
  return Promise.all(proms)
    .then(() => obj);
}
```

Note that, when using `.map` like this, only some of the items in the array will be Promises, but that's fine - the `Promise.all` will simply only wait for the *promises* in the array to resolve. Non-promises in the array (including `undefined` values) will simply be ignored.

Also, as always,
[There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - if you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either.